# Can't use if statement inside const declaration, but ternary operator works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm going through some coding examples, and came across this one example of a component declaration in React:

```
export const TodoList = ({ todos }) => (
    <ul>
        {
            todos && todos.length
            ? todos.map((todo, index) => {
                return <Todo key={`todo-${todo.id}`} todo={todo} />
            })
            : "No todos, yay!"
        }
    </ul>
);
```

I wanted to try and turn this ternary operator into an if/else statement, like this:

```
export const TodoList = ({ todos }) => (
    <ul>    
        {
            if (todos) && (todos.length) {
                todos.map((todo, index) => {
                    return <Todo key={`todo-${todo.id}`} todo={todo} />
                })
            } else {
                "No todos, yay!"
            }
        }
    </ul>
);
```

But, I get the error at the line where the `if` statement begins:

> **Parsing error: Unexpected token**

why is it that the ternary operator works here but an if statement doesn't?

Comment: `{…}` wraps an expression, like `2 + 2` or `x ? y : z`. An if statement is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: ah..I didn't know this. Thanks

Comment: In any case it would have to be `if (todos && todos.length)`. The parens are part of the `if` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What comes between the `{}`s must be an expression. The conditional (ternary) operator evaluates to an expression; `if`, on the other hand, is a statement which cannot be evaluated as an expression. For similar reasons, this is invalid:

```js
const foo = if (true) {
  'bar'
}
```

See [If-Else in JSX](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html):

> if-else statements don't work inside JSX. This is because JSX is just syntactic sugar for function calls and object construction. Take this basic example:
>
> ```
> // This JSX:
> ReactDOM.render(<div id="msg">Hello World!</div>, mountNode);
>
> // Is transformed to this JS:
> ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("div", {id:"msg"}, "Hello World!"), mountNode);
> ```
>
> This means that if statements don't fit in. Take this example:
>
> ```
> // This JSX:
> <div id={if (condition) { 'msg' }}>Hello World!</div>
>
> // Is transformed to this JS:
> React.createElement("div", {id: if (condition) { 'msg' }}, "Hello World!");
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The if statement is flow control, whereas the ternary operator is a simple operator. The if statement expects code, the ternary operator expects values.